# list certificate stored in user credentials

Tags: android, ssl, pkcs#12, android-7.0-nougat, android-7.1-nougat

In Android 7 Nougat, user installed certificate goes to "User credentials" instead of "Trusted credentials"(which consists of system credential & user credential).

I used to access "Trusted credentials" by:

```
KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidCAStore");
```

through the above code I can then access system & user trusted credentials.

But now, in Android 7, user installed certificate goes to a separate place called "User credentials" under `Settings --> Security --> User credentials`.

My question is how can I programmatically list the credentials inside `User credentials` in Android 7?

Comment: Reading the docs I would assume that an app has implicit access to the user certificates if configured via [<trust-anchors>](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html#trust-anchors) (as it is automatically done for apps for AP23 and below). I have not read anything that there is a way for explicitly access the user credentials store.

Comment: I added `<certificates src="user"/>` in `<trust-anchors>`, however, my app still doesn't trust my certificate that located under "User credentials".

Comment: I think you could be misunderstanding `Settings-->Security-->User credentials`. It shows the certificate & private keys installed by user, not the trusted certificates. Android6 can manage user certificates but you can not see them in settings,only the root CAs. When you install a PKCS#12, the private key is accesible in KeyChain, and the root CA can be installed as user trusted credential in `AndroidCAStore`. AndroidCAStore contains user&system entries and is what you are seeing in Android 6&7.If you are looking for a way to list private keys (the content of User credentials),there is no API.

Comment: @pedrofb, no, I am not misunderstanding, e.g. in Android 6 when I install my certificate & private key, it goes to `Settings ---> Security-->Trusted credentials(Users tab)`, but in Android 7, it goes to `Settings --> Security-->User credentials` which is not trusted. My question is how can I know in Android 7 my certificate is installed in `Settings-->Security-->User credential`? My certificate CAN NOT be listed from AndroidCAStore, I have tried it. AndroidCAStore only list trusted entries.

Comment: I have checked it with a real certificate both 6 & 7. In android 6, the intermediate certificates and root CA are installed in AndroidCAStore (not the leaf), but in android 7, it does not. You can see the certificate installed in `Settings-->Security-->User credential`, but the root CA is not installed in `AndroidCAStore`. You have to install it manually. I have exported the public certificate as `.cer`  from the `.pfx` and installed, and then is shown

Comment: Are you using a self-signed certificate?

Comment: @pedrofb, I am using a self-signed certificate. What you found is exactly the same as what I found. I am not sure why we discuss this which we both understand the same way. My question is how to programmatically check my self-signed certificate is installed in `Settings-->Security-->User credentials`. It seems there is no official API to do that. That's why I post this question.

Comment: I was lost with the difference between 6 and 7. But with a self-signed certificate I understand it now. When installed a p12 in 7 , the root CA (the certificate itself) is not installed as trusted, as in 6

Comment: @pedrofb, yes, let's see if anyone can suggest a workaround or solution to access `Settings-->Security-->User credentials` programmatically.

Comment: Match if alias name contains "user" string, if yes then you can list those as user-added credentials.

Comment: Did you find any answer ?

Answer (score 11):

To provide a more consistent and more secure experience across the Android ecosystem, beginning with Android Nougat, compatible devices trust only the standardized system `CAs` maintained in [AOSP](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/ca-certificates/).

Previously, the set of `pre-installed CAs` bundled with the system could vary from device to device. This could lead to compatibility issues when some devices did not include **CAs** that apps needed for connections as well as potential security issues if **CAs** that did not meet our security requirements were included on some devices.

> First, be sure that your CA needs to be included in the system. The
>   preinstalled CAs are only for CAs that meet our security requirements
>   because they affect the secure connections of most apps on the device.
>   If you need to add a CA for connecting to hosts that use that CA, you
>   should instead customize your apps and services that connect to those
>   hosts. For more information on [Customizing trusted CAs](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2016/07/changes-to-trusted-certificate.html).

In above [link](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2016/07/changes-to-trusted-certificate.html) you can find all the necessary information for trusting custom CAs with different needs like

1. Trusting custom CAs for debugging
2. Trusting custom CAs for a domain
3. Trusting user-added CAs for some domains
4. Trusting user-added CAs for all domains except some
5. Trusting user-added CAs for all secure connections

So, Basically you need to add a [Security Configuration File](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html#manifest) and [Configure a custom CA](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html#ConfigCustom)(For Android 7.0 (API level 24) and higher).

In Your **manifest.xml**

```
<manifest ... >
    <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
                    ... >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

In  **res/xml/network_security_config.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">example.com</domain>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw/my_ca"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

***Just for Information :-*** 
If you operate a CA that you believe should be included in Android, first complete the [Mozilla CA Inclusion Process](https://wiki.mozilla.org/CA:How_to_apply) and then file a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry) against Android to have the CA added to the standardized set of system CAs.

Let me know for any further help.

Hope this will help you. Keep Coding!!!

Comment: Tow questions: 1. for my app, I need to install my own root certificate to trust storage in Android 7. Are you saying  Mozilla CA Inclusion Process is a must to do process in order to have my root certificate being trusted by Android 7?

Comment: 2. What is `<domain includeSubdomains="true">example.com</domain>`, do I have to put this? What is this subdomain? I mean I know I have a root certificate to install to trust storage, but where I get the subdomain?

Comment: 1) Mozilla CA inclusion process is not must, it is just required if you want your CA in trusted credentials list in Android 7.0 and above.

Comment: 2) This is your domain and sub domains to which you want to make secure connection. If you want your custom CA to trust all domains than check #5 ' Trusting user-added CAs for all secure connections ' in this link. http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2016/07/changes-to-trusted-certificate.html?m=1

Comment: I still want to ask the Mozilla CA inclusion process. So, as you said "it is just required if you want your CA in trusted credentials list in Android 7.0 and above", there are two sub-lists in trusted credentials list, "System trusted" list & "User trusted" list, which list requires the Mozilla CA inclusion process? Both? I think I need my CA to be installed to the Settings-->Security--> trusted credentials (Users tab), I mean user trusted list.

Comment: As per documentation Mozilla CA inclusion process is required to add CA in standardized set of system CAs, so it will be for 'trusted' list. For 'User trusted' list I think when you add your certificate in 'network_security_config' you might see it in 'User trusted'(I didn't check it).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129051/discussion-between-pravin-d-and-mellon).

Answer (score 6):

In addition to changing how to configure the Ca (@Pravin D answer),Android has changed the way a pkcs12 certificate is loaded from 6 to 7. I highlight the important elements:

**When importing a pkcs12, is the root CA imported as trusted?**

- Android 6: Yes
- Android 7: No

**Where can I see the trusted credentials?**

- Android 6: `Settings ---> Security-->Trusted credentials` (system & user)
- Android 7: `Settings ---> Security-->Trusted credentials` (system & user tab)

**How to install user credentials?**

- Android 6: pkcs#12 file, certificate file, programmatically
- Android 7: pkcs#12 file( without private keys), certificate file, programmatically, custom CA configuration(@ Pravin D answer)

**Where can I see the user credentials (private keys)?**

- Android 6: not available from settings
- Android 7: `Settings-->Security-->User credentials`

**Is it possible to list user credentials programmatically?**

- Android 6: No
- Android 7: No

Reviewing Android code in depth, internal Android Keystore is wilfully hidden, only available to use from Android core classes. It is not possible to implement a workaround to list user credentials

Comment: What about in Android 7 install pkcs#12 with private key? How to install such certificate programmatically?

Comment: did you get any answer ?