# SSL/HTTPS with Android (Nougat) and Client Certificates

Tags: java, android, ssl, certificate, handshake

**Situation:**
I have a Airwatch Installment, that provides the Client with private "User Certificates" that are stored in the User private CA Store. The Certificates should be used when establishing a SSL Connection to a designated https Webserver.

E.g. When i try to access this Webserver via HTTPS and Chrome, Chrome finds the Client Certificate and asks me if i wanna use it (so not directly). By clicking "ok" i can establish the Connection and view the Site.

**Problem**
In the "recent times" this could be solved in custom Apps by providing the Apps themselfs with the physical Certificate and load it on runtime (by creating a Keystore, Trustmanager, and Custom SSLContext) as described [here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html)

I though with Android Nougat i could get rid of the "Workaround", by only configuring where the Certificates for this app are located. Its called Network Security Configuration, as described here https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html

So i Added:

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

in the Android Manifest, and added a XML that looks like this

```
<network-security-config>
    <base-config>
        <!-- Trust ONLY the mydomain.com Domain and its Subdomains -->
       <domain includeSubdomains="true">mydomain.com</domain>
       <trust-anchors>
           <!-- Trust preinstalled CAs -->
            <certificates src="system"/>
            <!-- Additionally trust user added CAs -->
            <certificates src="user"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

I though using a HttpsURLConnection would automatically use also the User-Certificates if necessary.

**Current Situation:**
Im Still getting this:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
```

**Question:**

1) Do I still have to Create a Custom SSLContext and injecting a Custom Trustmanager with a Custom Keystore ? And If I have to do so, how do I get the User Certificates ? The Defautl System CAs can be easyly initialised via `KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidCAStore");` but how to get the Keys from the User Specific Store to use them in the SSLContext ?

3) I didn't find any example in the Web how to Use a HttpsConnection with Client Certificates that are stored in the User Keystore on Android with Nougat or higher, any hints ?

Comment: this should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45984295/android-pre-lollipop-devices-giving-error-ssl-handshake-aborted-ssl-0x618d9c18

Comment: Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40363553 (the comments and the answers)?