# Get User certificates installed under user credentials on android device in c#

Tags: android, xamarin

I have .pkcs12 certificate and after installing it on android (5.0) device it is listing under settings->security->Trusted credentials->User tab.

with the help of below code I could able to list all the certificates including the one in system tab under Trusted credentials but I want only User certificates.

```
KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidCAStore");
```

I want to list out only user certificates and show it to user.

Thanks,
Vinod

Comment: You could refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40363553/list-certificate-stored-in-user-credentials/40743463

Comment: Did you find any answer ?